# Check if an object of generic type is in LinkedList

Tags: java, list, linked-list

I have a `LinkedList` of generic type `State`. In this `LinkedList` I have hundreds or even thousands of `State` objects. How can I, **in the most efficient way** to check if newly generated `State` object is already in the list?

State object:

```
public State(PlayerAddress player, LinkedList<BoxAddress> boxList, char[][] map, String solution, String stateHash) {
    this.player = player;
    this.boxList = boxList;
    this.map = map;
    this.solution = solution;
    this.stateHash = stateHash;
    boxListString = boxListToString(boxList);
    mapString = mapString(map);
}
}
```

Additionally, State object consists of another generic objects as it is shown in the Constructor. How can I check if both `State` objects are the same in every aspect (PlayerAddress, LinkedList, etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [the contains method?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) This could work. Also don't forget that you can overwrite stuff, so you could compare the hascodes as well by overwriting the hascode and compare methods.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would strongly suggest you will utilize the contains method. Which is the most efficient lookup for your case.

Looking at the java doc for contains:

> public boolean contains(Object o)
>   Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that   (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

So you should only need to overwrite equals for your State class. The hashcode, will be required for sets.

Comment: that's not true. lookup operation in linked list with thousands of elements is not efficient at all.

Comment: we are talking about working with a List, as far as I understand, it was not mentioned if a SET is required, etc.

Comment: the task was to find an efficient way.

Comment: if we are so explicit about fast and don't care about the implementation  and assume it's fine to change the actual data structure, I would recommend a library like [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/) which works nicely. I honestly assumed he would like to stay with hist list and not maintain 2 different collections, etcs. Especially since I had no idea about his available memory. We could even go further and move over to scala and utilize parallel collection, to further improve lookup times.